# JavaScript document.write is not working

Tags: javascript, document.write

Sorry if this seems dumb, i'm new to JavaScript.

This is in `menu.js`:

```
document.write("<a href="index.html">Home</a>");
document.write("<a href="news.html">News</a>");
document.write("<a href="about.html">About us</a>");
```

This is in `index.html`:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load `index.html`, nothing comes up...

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and you will know what the problem is.

Comment: Or better yet, use an editor that highlights these errors for you, so that they're caught even before you test it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your quotes, you're using `"` both to delimit your new elements and to set their `href` attribute, change your code to:

```
document.write("<a href='index.html'>Home</a>");
document.write("<a href='news.html'>News</a>");
document.write("<a href='about.html'>About us</a>");
```

Or:

```
document.write('<a href="index.html">Home</a>');
document.write('<a href="news.html">News</a>');
document.write('<a href="about.html">About us</a>');
```

Combining single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes. You could also escape your internal quotes (`document.write("<a href=\"index.html\">Home</a>");`

BUT it'd be better to use a single call to `document.write()`, like this:

```
document.write('<a href="index.html">Home</a>' 
    + '<a href="news.html">News</a>'
    + '<a href="about.html">About us</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not escaping the quotes in your strings.  It should be:

```
document.write("<a href=\"index.html\">Home</a>");
```

Otherwise, JavaScript thinks the string ends after `href=` and the rest of the line does not follow valid JavaScript syntax.

As @Felix mentioned, the JavaScript debugger tools will be extremely helpful in letting you know what's going on.